# Screen width and height in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am wondering how to get the screen width and height with Jetpack Compose?

Is there any way you can retrieve the screen dimensions other than
`getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()`?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You can achieve this with `LocalConfiguration.current`:

```
@Composable
fun PostView() {
  val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

  val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
  val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

  ...

}
```

Comment: For some weird reason, LocalConfiguration is giving me screenWidth of landscape orientation even though I switched from Landscape to Portrait. Is anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: If you want to get the size in pixels: `val screenDensity = configuration.densityDpi / 160f` and multiply with dp, for example `val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.toFloat() * screenDensity`. You might want to `round` to a whole number as well. since px is `Int`.

Comment: Probably a better way to get the size in pixels: 
`val density = LocalDensity.current; val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current; val screenWidthPx = with(density) {configuration.screenWidthDp.dp.roundToPx()}`

Comment: @AragornCrozier where does this `.roundToPx()` come from?

Comment: @hippietrail It's a function in `Density.kt`.

Comment: Note, that "screenHeightDp" doesn't include insets as per documentation: "The height of the available screen space in dp units excluding the area occupied by window insets, such as the status bar, navigation bar, and cutouts."

Answer (score 7):

Other workarounds include:-

A.) Declaring a `BoxWithConstraints` at the highest level of the hierarchy, then accessing the `maxHeight` and equivalent width attributes exposed inside the scope of the box

B.) Using custom layouts

```
Layout(
 content = { ... }
){ measurables, constraints ->
 //Exposes constraints.maxWidth, and a height equivalent
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**SOLUTION**

I am using this approach to get `ScreenWidth` and `ScreenHeight`. This works well for me and you can also use this for making responsive UI in `Jetpack Compose`

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSizeHelper() {
    
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val displayMetrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
    
    //Width And Height Of Screen
    val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels

    //Device Density
    val density = displayMetrics.density
    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's the best way to do it but you can try this:

```
class Size {
    @Composable
    fun height(): Int {
        val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
        return configuration.screenHeightDp
    }
    @Composable
    fun width(): Int {
        val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
        return configuration.screenWidthDp
    }
}
```

and then use this values like that :

```
val size = Size()
val screenHeight = size.height()

Box(modifier = Modifier.height((screenHeigh/2).dp)) {
    //content
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated here on this [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive):

*"Because the composable is not a screen-level composable, we also **should not use the current window metrics directly**, in order to maximize reusability."*

With `BoxWithConstraints` you will get the actual available size, not the full screen size.

It facilitates in some situation where you have paddings, for instance:

```
@Composable
fun Card(/* ... */) {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        if (maxWidth < 400.dp) {
            Column {
                //...
            }
        } else {
            Row{
              //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives you a `maxWidth` and a `maxHeight` to create your logic. More info here on [this Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive).

***Hope it helps!***

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me

```
@Composable
fun displayMe(){
  val isTablet = ((LocalConfiguration.current.screenLayout
                 and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                 >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
...
}
```