# How to calculate empty space in lazy column after last visible item

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

How to calculate empty space in lazy column after last visible item in Jetpack compose.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Modifier.onSizeChanged{intSize->}` on your LazyColumn and its parent Composble and check the distance between them.

One thing to note here is it requires another recomposition after getting size of parent and list. So you might need do to a check or refer this answer to get dimensions without recomposition

[How to get exact size without recomposition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition/73357119#73357119)

```
@Composable
private fun LazyColumnParentSizeSample() {

    var parentHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var listHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        .onSizeChanged {
            parentHeight = it.height
        }) {

        LazyColumn(modifier=Modifier.onSizeChanged {
            listHeight = it.height
        }){
            items(10) {
                Text("Item: $it")
            }
        }
        Text("listHeight: $listHeight, parent height: $parentHeight, difference: ${parentHeight-listHeight}")

    }
}
```

To get value in dp you can use `LocalDensity.current`

```
    val diffInDp = LocalDensity.current.run {(parentHeight-listHeight).toDp()  }
```

Comment: can you please add some sample code to understand better

Comment: Added sample code with `Modifier.onSizeChanged`

Comment: How to convert this height into DP ?

Comment: @TippuFisalSheriff updated answer. To convert to dp or convert from dp you can use `LocalDensity.current.run{value conversion here}`

Answer (score 2):

Use  `Modifier.onSizeChanged{}` to get the size of the LazyColumn

Comment: can you please add some sample code to understand better

Answer (score 2):

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.onSizeChanged(size ->

int columnHeight = size.height
int screenHeight = //getyourscreenheighthere by using window class

int remainingSpacae = screenHeight - columnHeight
```

))

open this link to get screen height ->

[Screen width and height in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919900/screen-width-and-height-in-jetpack-compose)