# Jetpack Compose Desktop: getting your display's height and width

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, desktop

I am looking for a way to get your display's height and width in Jetpack Compose for Desktop, but despite the fact that I've found some questions on SO ([Screen width and height in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919900/screen-width-and-height-in-jetpack-compose)), it's not very helpful, because there are no values (and other stuff) such as *LocalConfiguration*, only - *LocalViewConfiguration*, which is a different thing.

So, some words about my initial goal: I want to be able to **automatically** change the size of font used in my application: `textStyle = TextStyle(fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace, fontSize = calculateRelativeFontSize())`, where: `@Composable fun calculateRelativeFontSize(): TextUnit { val height = ...; val width = ...; ...}`

*Finally, I'm sorry if I'm missing something, because I'm not really a Kotlin or (honestly) Jetpack Compose programmer, just was asked to do some stuff...*

P.S. I'm working under Linux, so... maybe somehow (really don't believe in that)... (you got the point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that JetBrains Compose is built upon Skia and Java's AWT libraries. You can use their native functions relating to screen info. For instance using AWT:

```kotlin
// CloudsAnimation.kt
import org.jetbrains.skia.RuntimeEffect
import java.awt.Toolkit

@Composable
fun CloudsAnimation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().screenSize
    val screenHeight = screenSize.height
    val screenWidth = screenSize.width
    println("Width: $screenWidth ; Height: $screenHeight")
    // ... composables below etc

}
```

Running this on my 13 inch MacBook Pro :

```
Width: 1440 ; Height: 900
```

Comment: Odd, those imports resulted in unresolved references for me

Comment: @LabGecko it depends also on the sdk or build tool, also refer to this thread: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-236262/IDE-doesnt-start-Could-not-initialize-class-java.awt.Color
The sdk I was using on this answer is Azul 16

Comment: I was running Android Studio 2022.3.1 (Giraffe) Patch 1. I only see Visual C++ in that error report.

Comment: Do you have this in your dasktop app build config? withJava() ?
`kotlin { jvm { withJava()  }`