# How to get the correct fraction parameter for fillMaxHeight(...) and fillMaxWidth(...) in compose, if the initial value of the parameter is in dp?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, graphics, android-jetpack-compose

As I'm progressing with my latest personal project in kotlin, Android Studio, I've recently realised that I have to make my components scale uniformly on every type of screen irrespective of screen's resolution or dpi (density per inch). The problem is, till now, for all buttons, text fields, boxes, columns etc., I've set the height and width in dp (density-independent pixels). As a consequence, the physical size of the respective components is the same on each type of screen which leads to rendering problems. What I want is the widths and heights of all the components be proportionally the same on each type of screen. From what I found on the Internet I understand that the fastest way to make the transition to what I want is to use the functions fillMaxWeight() and fillMaxWidth() applied to the modifiers with the parameter "fraction".

Thus my question is, how do I get that subunitary value if I have the current_value in dp and the screen resolution of the base case phone I simulated on in the emulator? Is it just a ratio like: currentHeight/screenHeight or currentWidth/screenWidth? And how do I get the screenHeight and screenWidth of the screen? Regarding the last question, I've already read this post:

[geting the screen's width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919900/screen-width-and-height-in-jetpack-compose)

What I want to ask more is if the first answer is entirely correct, regarding the case of changing the orientation of the screen? Does it still give the correct values for the screen's width and height? I attach the code snippet of the answer below.

```
@Composable
fun PostView() {
  val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

  val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
  val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

  ...

}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So, I realize my question might have been a bit too specific, but after trying one way of solving it, I decided I should share the results.

Basically, as I've somehow already mentioned in my question, I used the ratios:

**current_Height / screen_Height**
and
**current_Width / screen_Width**.

The values **current_Height** and **current_Width** are some hardcoded values of the height and width measured in dps which worked only on one type of screen that was the starting test case. In addition, the **screen_Height** and **screen_Width** values were obtained as in the code snippet provided in the question. After all, I used as much as I could the following functions:

**modifier.fillMaxWidth(fraction = ...)** or **modifier.fillMaxHeight(fraction = ...)** instead of just hardcoding the numerical values in dps for width and height.

Finally, I checked the outcome on 3 different resolutions:

720 x 1280,

1080 X 2400,

1440 X 3120

and it seems that there are not any rendering problems.

I still didn't checked the case for changing the orientation of the screen. If I'll do, I'll come back with an update.