How to make a specific item in a LazyColumn occupy full screen width in Jetpack Compose?
I'm using a LazyColumn with a maximum width of 600.dp in Jetpack Compose. I want one specific item in the list to stretch and occupy the full screen width. Is there a way to achieve this without applying padding to each item?
 val list = listOf("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Full width", "Normal", "Normal")
        LazyColumn(Modifier.widthIn(max = 600.dp)) {
            items(list) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .background(
                            if (it == "Full width") {
                                Color.Red
                            } else {
                                Color.Black
                            },
                        ),
                ) {
                    Text(text = it)
                }

            }
        }



Just to make sure I undestand correctly, you want the "Full width" item to be wider than the LazyColumn which is limited to 600.dp, you want it to take up the entire screen width, right?

Yes that correct.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919900/screen-width-and-height-in-jetpack-compose

That won't work

can you try something like like modifier = Modifier
.then(
if (item == "Full width") {
Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
} else {
Modifier.widthIn(max = 600.dp)
}
)

Can you update the image with what you want the result to look like? I did not understand the question

Try this

val list =
    listOf("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Full width", "Normal", "Normal")
LazyColumn(Modifier.widthIn(max = 600.dp)) {
    items(list) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .then(
                    if (it == "Full width") {
                        Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    } else {
                        Modifier.widthIn(max = 200.dp)
                    }
                )
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .background(
                    if (it == "Full width") {
                        Color.Red
                    } else {
                        Color.Black
                    },
                ),
        ) {
            Text(text = it)
        }

    }
}


Already tried that it won't if you change you preview size, just change it to @Preview(widthDp = 800, heightDp = 500).

Ended up solving it by changing modifier to
Modifier
   .wrapContentWidth(unbounded = true)
   .fillMaxWidth()
   .wrapContentHeight()

